# how to move over to 'algorithm: auto' for the encoder in existing projects by upgrading to 4.3?

Tags: security, symfony4, password-encryption, symfony-4.3

We recently started a project where users have early access to it.
In advance we used bcypt algorithm for the encoder and now upgrading to 4.3 gives us a deprecated warning to change the algorithm to auto instead.

I tried to set this up but got 401 bad_credentials as answer, as of the encoder encodes the passwords differently and there is no match of course.

I try no to keep any deprecated warnings in the code, so an up to date framework is preferred (a must).

Is there a seamless way to move over the auto algorithm? or I should try to write an EventListener/Subscriber which converts it in the pre-authentication phase.